# After update angular to 1.3, resource not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Before update angular, all code worked and i dont have problems with it, but after update, i have crash in line

```
        return $resource('/admin/:url/:id', null,
```

Screen my error - http://prntscr.com/51zomi

My service

```js
DataPage.$inject = ['$resource'];
    function DataPage ($resource) {
        return $resource('/admin/:url/:id', null,
            {
                'update': { method:'PUT' }
            });

    }
```

I calling it so

```js
$scope.pages  = DataPage.get({id:page.id, url:'sport_pages'});
            $scope.pages.$promise['finally'](function(){
               $scope.loading = false;
            });
```

But i have error message.....

Help me pls, how i can fix it?

**UPDATED!!**

Angular 1.3 more strong json parse. I'm have invalid json in my response and angular display error.... All thanks.

Comment: Can you please attach the syntax for the module declaration for the service?

Comment: angular.module('admin.pages').service('DataPage', DataPage);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an issue with Angular 1.3, but there is a possibility that:

- null isn't valid specification of data used to get resource
- null for sure isn't good for a resource that has parameters used in the path

This is what works for me:

**Without parameters**

```
return $resource('api/groups', {}, {});
```

Call:

```
Groups.get();
```

**With parameters (your case)**

```
return $resource('messages/:lang/:packageName.json',
        {packageName: '@packageName', lang: '@lang'}, {});
```

Call:

```
Messages.get({
            packageName: 'base',
            lang: $scope.lang
        });
```

I know it looks redundant, but it works great.

*Edit: In my opinion the error is thrown while parsing your path and encountering letter `u` after `:` char and not finding suitable parameter in the second parameter of `$resource` function, but that's just a guess*

Comment: i'm try this. This example described in official angular docs, but this not working......

Comment: Are you importing angular-resources and angular in the same 1.3 version? Maybe you could post some more code or better a fiddle? I'll look into it tomorrow and post my complete resource and controller code.